# Android External Storage Visibility

Tags: android, file, text, storage, external

I am building an android application that must write data to a text file that can be accessed when I plug my Nexus 7 into my PC so I can drag the text file onto my desktop.

I read that External Storage is insecure so this can be done easily, and Internal Storage is secure data that can not be edited or touched. But I also read that external storage talks specifically about SD cards etc and internal storage is the actual physical drive, my Nexus 7 does NOT have an SD card reader.. does this mean I cannot write things that can be visible?

How does this work? I am confused about the difference between the 2.. if I 'write' a textfile via I/O, where will it go? can I specify it go to a certain folder?

I am worried I need to buy another tablet for my project -,-

Comment: Nexus has no sdcard. But it has external storage. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them and read the note under `getExternalStorageDirectory()` @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Okay I understand, how would I go about writing to external rather than internal? is it a different function or something?

Comment: Use `File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"my folder");`. Make sure you have permission in manifest file. Now check if file exists else create one. read saving files that are app private http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 0):

Any android device have a shared directory that can be edited by all the applications. In most of the cases it will be your SD-CARD how ever it dose not have to be like that.

When you mount your device to PC, and use the "mount as driver" option. You should access to this directory from your PC.

How ever in my opinion to improve the user experience you should develop a desktop side application that will communicate with your phone and extract all the data that it needs. Also sending the information using email could be an option.